# pasar de código html+php de un archivo a una variable en otro archivos

Tags: php, html, variables, template

tengo esto:

```
$DISPLAYHEADER= '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en-US">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <title>'.TITLE.'></title>
                <!-- Icono  de la web -->
                <link rel="shortcut icon"   href="sources/img/logos/favicon.ico" />
                <link rel="icon"            href="sources/img/logos/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
                <!-- CSS Framework -->
                <link rel="stylesheet"      href="sources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </head>
        ';
```

pero quisiera sacar la parte del codigo + el TITULO a un archivo aparte algo como:

```
$DISPLAYHEADER= file_get_contents(FILEROOT.'/source/tpl/header.php');
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en-US">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <title><?=@TITLE?></title>
                    <!-- Icono  de la web -->
                    <link rel="shortcut icon"   href="sources/img/logos/favicon.ico" />
                    <link rel="icon"            href="sources/img/logos/favicon.png" type="image/png" />
                    <!-- CSS Framework -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet"      href="sources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                </head>
```

como verán aquí el detalle es que debe preservar el uso de la constante Title y guardar todo el contenido en  `$DISPLAYHEADER`

## ERROR:

```
me imprime el Literal del titulo y no el valor de la contante.
```

Comment: cambia el file_get_contents por requiere

Answer (score 0):

Olvídate de las variables: NO ($DISPLAYHEADER). Tienes que escribir el código html y php de forma normal.

Debes usar las sentencias 'require' o 'include' para aquellas partes del código que quieras modular e incluirlas a través de archivos externos (.php). Tú escribes esas partes (en este caso el head) en otros archivos de forma natural y fin.

Ejm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php require './head.php'; ?>

<body>
... // Todo lo demás
```

Ten en cuenta que 'require' e 'include' son lo mismo, lo único que si se produce un error de carga con 'require' la página se detendrá con un error fatal. Mientras que un error en 'include' producirá solo una advertencia y en ningún caso la detención del script. A la hora de usar uno de los dos debes ponderar si la página web necesita si o si incluir ese archivo o puede seguir funcionando sin el.

La variable 'title' yo la declararía después de la tag 'DOCTYPE html' y antes del 'require', pero esto es a gustos. Las variables tienen el 'scope' normal de php: Si las incluyes en una función no tendrán alcance fuera de ella, a no ser que uses 'global'.

Comment: Wordpress tiene sus propios hooks: wp_head(), get_header( $name ), etc

Comment: ya lo resolví por otra vía con diccionarios gracias igual.

Answer (score 0):

fue necesario usar una funcion como esta:

```
public function FileGetCont($Path, $data = '')
    {
        $Dir = FILEROOT.$Path;
        if (!file_exists($Dir)) {
            $File = false;
        } else {
            ob_start();
            include $Dir;
            $File = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        return $File;
    }
```

donde `$Path` es el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo `*.php`.
y $data es un `array` con la informacion que se va a remplazar en el archivo `*.php`.

para hacer la traducción mas rápida se implemento la siguiente funcion que remplaza el texto entre llaves `{example}` por su traduccion:

```
public function getTranslation($data)
    {
        #Usado
        $dic = CoreApp::$ovars['TRANSLATION']; //uso un objeto para guardar el diccionario en esta posicion.
        foreach ($dic as $key => $value) {
            $data = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $data);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```